# Creality Ender 6 does not boot beyond the boot screen

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-6

My Creality Ender 6 has stopped moving beyond the boot screen.

It kind of happened suddenly. Another thing is that I have a red light on the motherboard at the D2 location that is turned on continuously after I turn on the printer. The screen is stuck on boot.

What happened before the problem:
The distance between the nozzle and the bed was low, so there was a lot of accumulation of polymer. I had to clean much of it manually after I saw it had built up significantly. It had accumulated so much that it was even touching the internal fan, and got accumulated on some of the wirings on the printhead as well. I broke a portion of the fan's fin in cleaning out the then solidified polymer. After I turned the printer off and turned it back on once the cleaning was done, it got stuck on the boot screen and has not moved beyond that point despite my trying different things.

Can anyone advise what could be the potential sources of the problem and how these could be resolved?

Comment: If you could [edit] in more details of what happened prior to the printer no longer booting beyond the boot screen, this would help in diagnosing a problem.

Comment: Have you tried to unplug (while not powered!) all connections except for the display and power lines and start/boot the printer?

Comment: @agarza, the distance between the nozzle and the bed was low, so there was a lot of accumulation of polymer. I had to clean much of it manually after I saw it had built up significantly. It had accumulated so much that it was even touching the internal fan, and got accumulated on some of the wirings on the printhead as well. I broke a portion of the fan's fin in cleaning out the then solidified polymer. After I turned the printer off and turned it back on once the cleaning was done, it got stuck on the boot screen and has not moved beyond that point despite my trying different things.

Comment: @Oscar, I have.